# Java 8 BigDecimal multiply method losing precision when being inverted

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

Java 8 here. According to Google:

- Converting pounds to kilograms: [multiply by 0.453592](https://www.google.com/search?ei=EzWLWu-nLqafjwSK2avgBA&q=convert+pound+to+kilogram&oq=convert+pound+to+kilogram&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l8.19422.19422.0.19661.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.YmCE8djCb0A)
- Converting kilograms to pounds: [multiply by 2.20462](https://www.google.com/search?ei=NjWLWuiwFOHXjwTGn4KIDw&q=convert+kilogram+to+pound&oq=convert+kilogram+to+pound&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i20i263k1j0j0i22i30k1l8.2671.5677.0.5829.13.13.0.0.0.0.264.1414.1j5j2.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.7.1172...0i7i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.0uHSoj_LNqo)
- Converting inches to meters: [multiply by 0.0254](https://www.google.com/search?ei=PDWLWuPkO6XNjwTc67ToCg&q=convert+inch+to+meter&oq=convert+inch+to+meter&gs_l=psy-ab.3...12538.14145.0.14255.9.7.0.0.0.0.316.316.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..8.1.316...0i7i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.nu8VVUG09UU)
- Converting meters to inches: [multiply by 39.3701](https://www.google.com/search?ei=TDWLWuqxCITjjwSslpP4BQ&q=convert+meter+to+inch&oq=convert+meter+to+inch&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l7j0i20i263k1.11538.13160.0.13417.9.7.0.0.0.0.354.599.2-1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..7.2.598...0i7i30k1j0i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.1mTCB4u4azo)

So I whipped up this little Java code:

```
public class MeasurementConverter {
    private static final int SCALE = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MeasurementConverter().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        BigDecimal hundredLbs = new BigDecimal(100.00);
        BigDecimal hundredInches = new BigDecimal(100.00);

        System.out.println(hundredLbs + " pounds is " + poundsToKilos(hundredLbs) + " kilos and converts back to " + kilosToPounds(poundsToKilos(hundredLbs)) + " pounds.");
        System.out.println(hundredInches + " inches is " + inchesToMeters(hundredInches) + " meters and converts back to " + metersToInches(inchesToMeters(hundredInches)) + " inches.");
    }

    private BigDecimal metersToInches(BigDecimal meters) {
        return meters.multiply(new BigDecimal("39.3701").setScale(SCALE, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    }

    private BigDecimal inchesToMeters(BigDecimal inches) {
        return inches.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.0254").setScale(SCALE, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    }

    private BigDecimal kilosToPounds(BigDecimal kilos) {
        return kilos.multiply(new BigDecimal("2.20462").setScale(SCALE, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    }

    private BigDecimal poundsToKilos(BigDecimal pounds) {
        return pounds.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.45359").setScale(SCALE, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    }
}
```

When it runs it prints out:

```
100 pounds is 45.00 kilos and converts back to 99.0000 pounds.
100 inches is 3.00 meters and converts back to 118.1100 inches.
```

Whereas I was *expecting* it to print out:

```
100.00 pounds is 45.00 kilos and converts back to 100.00 pounds.
100.00 inches is 3.00 meters and converts back to 100.00 inches.
```

All I care about is that Imperial<->Metric conversion is accurate up to 2 decimal places and that the final outputs are always accurate up to 2 decimal places. **Can anyone see where I'm going awry and what the fix is?**

Comment: Note that 100 pounds is 45.36 kilos, and 100 inches is 2.54 metres.

Comment: Remember that passing a `double` to `new BigDecimal` loses precision, because you're not using the exact value, but rather the closest representable value as a double. Use `new BigDecimal("39.37")` etc instead. Also remember that those reciprocals aren't exact, so 39.37*0.0254=0.999998, not 1.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner (+1) however please see my updates with your proposed changes. Conversions are still *way* off! Any ideas?

Comment: My previous comment is a hint.

Comment: Increase the scale.

Comment: Arent the SCALE and HALF_UP arguments for the multiply? you adding it only to the BigDecimal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the brackets messed up. Consider this:

```
kilos.multiply(new BigDecimal("2.20462").setScale(SCALE, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

Here you first set scale on `2.20462` which results in `2.20` and then multiply.

Now consider the reverse conversion:

```
pounds.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.45359").setScale(SCALE, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

Here you effectively multiply by `0.45`. And `2.2*0.45=0.99` which explains the result.

You have set scale on the result of the multiplication, not on the multiplicator. Basically the last bracket is on the wrong place. It should be something like:

```
pounds.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.45359")).setScale(SCALE, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Here's the [corrected code](https://ideone.com/cFHXSJ).

Comment: But why bother with the `setScale` at all?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It's in the question, as the OP.

Comment: Indeed - what I'm suggesting is that the answer should be "just remove the `setScale`" ;)  (And then put it in the output formatting)

Answer (score 3):

Arent the SCALE and HALF_UP arguments for the multiply? you adding it only to the BigDecimal.

I think you want:

```
inches.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.0254"), new MathContext(SCALE, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

Chaning SCALE to 8 and using your code with the MathContext resulted in:

```
100 pounds is 45.35900 kilos and converts back to 99.999359 pounds.
100 inches is 2.5400 meters and converts back to 100.00005 inches.
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcos (+1) - how expensive/heavy is that new `MathContext` instance? Is there a way to create it only once at app startup? I ask because in the wild these methods will be getting hit **all** the time...

Comment: I think the MathContext will only apply AFTER the calculation

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion factors are off. You're rounding the conversion factors to only 2 decimal places:

```
private static final int SCALE = 2;
[...]    
new BigDecimal("0.0254").setScale(SCALE, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

Thus, *"0,0254"* gets rounded up to *0.03*, which doesn't fit your "reverse" conversion factor of *39.37*. That's why your reversal doesn't equal the original value.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing rounding in the middle of the conversion. Therefore, the input value for the reverse operation is already off.

If you want to display the values as:

```
100.00 pounds is 45.00 kilos and converts back to 100.00 pounds.
100.00 inches is 3.00 meters and converts back to 100.00 inches.
```

Remove `setScale` from all your private methods. For example:

```
private BigDecimal metersToInches(BigDecimal meters) {
    return meters.multiply(new BigDecimal("39.3701"));
}
```

Then you can simply format the output with your desired format:

```
private BigDecimal formatOutput(BigDecimal value) {
    return value.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).setScale(SCALE);
}
```

Finally:

```
System.out.println(hundredLbs + " pounds is " + formatOutput(poundsToKilos(hundredLbs)) + " kilos and converts back to " + formatOutput(kilosToPounds(poundsToKilos(hundredLbs))) + " pounds.");
System.out.println(hundredInches + " inches is " + formatOutput(inchesToMeters(hundredInches)) + " meters and converts back to " + formatOutput(metersToInches(inchesToMeters(hundredInches))) + " inches.");
```

Gives:

```
100.00 pounds is 45.00 kilos and converts back to 100.00 pounds.
100.00 inches is 3.00 meters and converts back to 100.00 inches.
```

Alternatively, if you want to display value with decimal places you can simply change the `formatOutput` method to:

```
private BigDecimal formatOutput(BigDecimal value) {
    return value.setScale(SCALE, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

Which will print out the values in the following way (I'd say it is better and correct!)

```
100.00 pounds is 45.36 kilos and converts back to 100.00 pounds.
100.00 inches is 2.54 meters and converts back to 100.00 inches.
```